# TaskCanceledException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting this error on the first app http request when the app starts up. This occurs in both Android and iOS, it does not happen every time and I cannot reliably replicate it, repeating the same request afterwards works correctly.

```
Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'.
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00245] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:410 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00c5c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs:551 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0129b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs:739 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpConnection connection, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000e6] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:330 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00101] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:296 
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d7] in <831b7afb4f024d399aa7f21c2ef99b9c>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendCoreAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000dc] in <fdbe77d51f99428cbaad707c9b22e67a>:0 
at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult] (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Polly.ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, Polly.ResultPredicates`1[TResult] shouldRetryResultPredicates, System.Func`5[T1,T2,T3,T4,TResult] onRetryAsync, System.Int32 permittedRetryCount, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sleepDurationsEnumerable, System.Func`4[T1,T2,T3,TResult] sleepDurationProvider, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x0012e] in <ab401ba6fe434cfbb0784f458cf3f3ea>:0 
at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1[TResult].ExecuteAsync (System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] action, Polly.Context context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) [0x0009f] in <ab401ba6fe434cfbb0784f458cf3f3ea>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00126] in <fdbe77d51f99428cbaad707c9b22e67a>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ef] in <831b7afb4f024d399aa7f21c2ef99b9c>:0 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:506 
at App.Method`1[T].GetRequestAsync[O] (System.String url, System.Boolean useBackground) [0x0015d] in <9aeb34a0def84b7dbbba21e6fb8b9f0d>:0
```

Any solutions or causes of this issue

Error occurs on

```
var client = service.GetClient();
await client.GetAsync(url); //Exception
```

Client is generated from httpfactory, which is built on app startup

```
services.AddSingleton<Helpers.ClientService>();
services.AddHttpClient("webClient", client =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = GenerateAuthHeader();
}).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
  .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
```

```
public class ClientService
{
    IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    public ClientService(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = factory;
    }
    public HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        return _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("webClient");
    }
}
```

Comment: **Show relevant code.** Then do enough debugging to find out **which line** of that code results in the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more advice about asking questions here.

Comment: Curious why you are usin `SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))`?

Comment: The theory was to recycle the client faster in case an underlying part was becoming invalid causing the above error, however it has not seemed to effect anything